# Fatal error: Call to undefined method - does not completely

Tags: php, mysqli

this is how I would like to be able to Update quick and easy, so I could select from the database and the same time updater content that I have right in.

this is how I get this error:
**Fatal error: Call to undefined method mebe::BOXforside() in /home/jesperbo/public_html/blabla.dk/admin_forside.php on line 30**

Admin_forside.php show you here:

```
<?php
  $forside_tekst = $mebe->BOXforside();
?>
```

into my large file where I get all my information looks like this:
*fun_db.php*

```
function BOXforside()
    {
        if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("SELECT `tekst` FROM `forside_tekst`")) { 
            $stmt->execute();

            $stmt->bind_result($tekst);

            while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            ?>
            <form action="#" method="post">
                <textarea name="tekst" cols="20" rows="15" class="new" style="width:100%;"><?php echo $tekst;?></textarea>
                <input type="submit" name="opret" value="Opret Blog" class="new"></td>
            </form>
            <?php
            }

            $stmt->close();

        } else {
            echo 'Der opstod en fejl i erklæringen: ' . $this->mysqli->error;
        }


            if(isset($_POST["opret"]))
            {

                if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare('UPDATE `forside_tekst` SET `tekst`=? WHERE `id`=?')) { 
                    $stmt->bind_param('si', $tekst, $id);

                    $tekst = $_POST["tekst"]; 
                    $id = 1;

                    $stmt->execute();

                    $stmt->close();

                }
            }

    }
```

When I download files it looks like this on the toppe af **admin_forside.php**

```
session_start();
require_once ("indhold/inc/fun_db.php"); //download alle my files to it site.
$mebe = new mebe;
$db = $mebe->db_c();
error_reporting(E_ERROR); //take alle error away
```

**I do not see why I can not get it to work.**

Comment: Make sure you close all open curly brackets before your method's definition.

Comment: Is BOXforside() a class method of class mebe? Looking at the code you posted it looks like regular function. If its just a function simply use `$forside_tekst = BOXforside();`

Comment: what do you mean completely?, try to show it?

Comment: @MichaelThessel my class its "mebe"

Comment: `class mebe
{

}`  its a my "class"